# Can't send HTML SUBMIT form as email with phpmailer

Tags: php, html, forms

so I have a PHPMailer that does send an email. BUT! I need to send this submit form, it's like a little survey, to my email. My school wants an HTML file and a PHP file so I can't just make a form in PHP.

```
<                                                                           
<<!DOCTYPE html>
<
<<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Survey</title>
<style type="text/css">

fieldset {
width: 75%;
border: 2px solid #ff0000;
color: blue;
}

legend {
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 125%;
}

label.question {
width: 225px;
float: left;
text-align: left;
font-weight: bold;
}

span.question {
font-weight: bold;
}
input, textarea, {
 border: 1px solid #000;
 padding: 3px;
 }

  #buttons {
  margin-top: 12px;
   }

   </style>
   </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Quick Survey!</h1>
    <form name="qsForm" method="post" action="Send Form.php">

    <fieldset>
    <legend>Personal Information</legend>

        <p><label class="question" for="the_name">
        What's your name?</label>
       <input type="text" id="the_name" name="the_name" 
       placeholder="Enter your full name."
       size="50" required autofocus></p>

        <p><label class="question" for="the_email">What is your e-mail address? 
 </label>
    <input type="email" id="the_email" name="the_email"
      placeholder="Use a real one please!"
     size="50" required></p>
      </fieldset>

     <fieldset>
     <legend>Survey Questions</legend>

     <p><span class="question">Which animated movies are your favorite?</span><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="this_one" name="some_options[]"
    value="Megamind.It's really funny and a great superhero movie.">
    <label for="this_one">Megamind. It's really funny and a great superhero movie. 
     </label><br>
     <input type="checkbox" id="this_one" name="some_options[]"
      value="Jungle Book. It's a classic!">
     <label for="this_one">Jungle Book. It's a classic!</label><br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="this_one" name="some_options[]"
       value="Toy Story 3. Actually made me cry...*sniff sniff*.">
         <label for="this_one">Toy Story 3. Actually made me cry...*sniff sniff*. 
 </label><br>
       <input type="checkbox" id="this_one" name="some_options[]"
      value="Madagascar. I like to move it move it lol.">
     <label for="this_one">Madagascar. I like to move it move it lol.</label><br>
     <input type="checkbox" id="this_one" name="some_options[]"
    value="Zootopia. I just really love Nick Wild!">
   <label for"this_one">Zootopia. I just really love Nick Wild!</label><br>
   <input type="checkbox" id="this_one" name="some_options[]"
    value="Finding Dory. I don't remember why I love this movie.">
    <label for"this_one">Finding Dory. I don't remember why I love this movie.</label><br>
 <input type="checkbox" id="this_one" name="some_options[]"
value="Spirit. I love how his mane moves in the wind! Beautiful Movie!">
<label for="this_one">Spirit. I love how his mane moves in the wind! Beautiful Movie! 
 </label></p>
  <p><label for="choose_rating"><span class="question">Please rate my survey on a 
  scale 
  of 1(dumb) to 10(pretty cool):</span></label>
 <input type="number" id="choose_rating" name="choose_rating"
  min="0" max="10" step="1" placeholder="Please be honest"></p>

 </fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend>Send Me A Message!</legend>
<p><label for="message"><span class="question">Feel free to send constructive 
critisism, commendation, etc.:</span></label>
<textarea id="message" name="message" rows="7" columns="55">
</textarea></p>
</fieldset>
<div id="buttons">
<input type="submit" value="Click here to submit"> or
<input type="reset" value="Erase and start over">
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<
<
<
<
```

This is the HTML file. I need to send the message part to my email. Whatever the person enters into the box. It should be able to come from any email the person puts in.
Is there a way to get this PHP file to send the form?

```
<<?php

 ini_set('SMTP', 'localhost' );
 ini_set('sendmail_from', 'my other email');


  require 'includes/phpmailer.php';
  require 'includes/SMTP.php';
  require 'includes/Exception.php';

  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
   use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->isSMTP();

    $mail->Host ="SMTP.gmail.com";

     $mail->SMTPAuth="true";

     $mail->SMTPSecure="ssl";

     $mail->Port="465";

     $mail->Username="my other email ";

     $mail->Password="My other email password";

      $mail->Subject="Test Email";

      $mail->setFrom("my other email");

      $mail->Body="Hello.";

       $mail->addAddress("MY official Email");

        $mail->isHTML(true);

         if($mail->Send()) {
         echo "Email sent..!";
            }else{
             echo "Error..!";
               }

             $mail->smtpClose();
              ?>
             
<
<
<
<
<
<
```

Comment: Provide a link to form instead. Forms are very limited inside emails.

Comment: Have you done any tests, did you get any error ?

Comment: (1) Please provide full url in your form action (so use `action="http://www.xxxx.com/SendForm.php"` instead of `action="SendForm.php"`)  (2) FYI, Some of the email clients will block form submission in email (3) [side note] Please make sure you have set the correct settings so that you can use smtp service of gmail.

Comment: What is with all the random `<` characters in the HTML & PHP? Is that the actual code??

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow nai. *"Is there a way to get this PHP file to send the form?"* - yes, but you have to decide how those form inputs are to be represented in the email. if you want to put them as `body` content of your email you could just put the form inputs in with a grocery list style (e.g. `some_options: "Megamind.." (new line) message: "some message was here"`).

Comment: That white space in `Send Form.php` in your action, is likely to break.